# setting up Ubuntu 22.04.2 with Pi-Hole on a dual nic card network

Tags: networking

ok here go's,(Pi-Hole is installed & runs good)(everything is 1gb wired conn.) I have my modem/internet going to my Netgear WNDR3700v3 router - going to the ubuntu box into 1 nic card with a static Ip address, I want to connect my 8 port network switch to a second nic card (installed & working) to send to pc's (all windows) & Roku's. Getting Ip's & settings to make it all work is above my pay grade:( Hope this isn't to lacking in what I'm trying to do:/ I'm not good at all (1st time) with Linux but I'm trying :) I'm lost now & my cats no help at all:( THX for any help!

Guy